# Spring security 3.0: SavedRequest always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application I'm using Spring Security 3.0 and in the class used to intercept the "post-authentication" I have something like:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
...
   }
}
<security:http>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login/" always-use-default-target="false"  authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler" authentication-failure-url="/login/?login_error=1"/>
 ...
</security:http>

<bean id="customAuthenticationHandler" class="org.myproject.CustomAuthenticationHandler"/>
```

When I log in from a generic page "X" inside the application I expect to be redirect after successful authentication to "X" but I always land to the home page.
The 'savedRequest' variable above returns always null. Is there any specific setting missing? How can I get the correct redirection?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by 'log in from a generic page "X" inside the application'.

If you mean you are already viewing that page and then choose to access the login page (or you have an embedded login form in it) then you will not be redirected to page "X", since Spring Security has no idea what page you were at when you decided to log in. You would have to either redirect to the location given by the `Referer` header, or store the page view history in your application logic.

The `SavedRequest` mechanism is only used in the case where you try to access a protected resource and Spring Security needs to redirect you to the login page. It makes a temporary note of the location so that it can attempt to restore the original request behaviour after login.

If "X" was a protected page and you attempted to view it, a `SavedRequest` with the URL of "X" *would* be cached in the session while you were redirected to the login page.

Comment: For page 'X' I meant a generic *not* protected page (so u don't need to log in to see it). This page has on top classical <a href="/login">. According you said in my case I should use either  "Referer" header or page-view history. "Referer" doesn't work for me as in onAuthenticationSuccess request.getHeader("referer"); == localhost:8080/login. For a normal "a-href" the page-view history is the only solution?

Comment: Referer will only work for an embedded login form. When Spring Security processes a login form submission, it has no general way knowing which page you were on when you clicked the login link, so you would have to store that information somewhere.